# Reordering divs with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there anyway to obtain the following div layout with the use of already defined Bootstrap 3 classes? I want to avoid using a media query if at all possible.

**Desktop**

[         1         ][ 2 ]
[            3                ]

**Mobile**

[            1            ]
[            3            ]
[            2            ]

I've tried coding the divs with mobile first in mind and pushing and pulling to change the order on desktop, but with this particular layout using those classes just pushes and pulls the div out of the viewport, vs wrapping them within the 12 column grid and moving them up or down a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:grey">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-8" style="background-color:blue">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-4" style="background-color:red">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col col-12" style="background-color:green">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

using the column grid feature of Bootstrap should solve your request.
[References - Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Edit: My mistake, code fixed and here is a bootply 
[example](https://www.bootply.com/JfM7dSAipu)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible with Bootstrap 3. If you could update it to Bootstrap 4, you could reorder them with the flex layout.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 order-0 order-sm-0">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 order-2 order-sm-1">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 order-1 order-sm-2">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Beware that Bootstrap is mobile first and the classes should be used from smallest to widest.